# JavaScript/HTML: How to use window.onload=x together with body onLoad="setTimeout('myFunction()',4000);"

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I'm using `body onLoad="setTimeout('myFunction()',4000);"` to refresh my website every 4 seconds. I want to use another JavaScript that will make my text fade. It works, but then my website won't refresh every 4 seconds. It's either fade or refresh. They interfere with each other.

The text fading Script needs `window.onload=fade` in order to work, but if I use it, it will overwrite the `body onLoad="setTimeout('myFunction()',4000);"` - how do I make both work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
body onLoad="fade(); setTimeout(myFunction, 4000);"
```

instead of the `window.onload` call or use:

```
window.onload = function () {
    fade();
    setTimeout(myFunction, 4000);
};
```

instead of the body `onload`.

You could also add multiple event listeners (as they are the preferred approaches) instead of using the above methods.

```
function onPageLoad() {
    fade();
    setTimeout(myFunction, 4000);
    return;
};

if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("load", onPageLoad);
}
else if (document.attachEvent) {
    document.attachEvent("onload", onPageLoad);
}
else {
    // event handling not supported
}
```

Comment: I did. For some reason I had to wait 10 minutes from the time I asked my question in order to do so.

Comment: @EliUnger Yes the limit has been set by StackOverflow to prevent spam. Thanks!

Comment: Putting the two methods into the body onLoad fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

This should work universally, although I haven't tested it :)

```
(function(window) {
    var _onload = window.onload;

    window.onload = function() {
        _onload && _onload();
        setTimeout(myFunction, 4000);
    }
}(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.setInterval(myFunction, 4000);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this run the function every 4 seconds?